# MultiSelect with formControlName

Tags: angular, primeng

I tried to use the PrimeNG MultiSelect with a reactive form. When I try to select one item, all the items in my MultiSelect are selected and it displays undefined.
You can find the code in the [`Plunker`](https://plnkr.co/edit/109mbu?p=preview)

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? If so please accept the answer or provide feedback regarding additional issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to a working plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/h9gIWu2PTpd7vZt2j5qj?p=preview

It looks like this component is unable to determine which fields are value fields and which fields are label fields. I set the networks array to an any array and manually set the property identifiers as label/value.

```js
    public networks: any[] = [];
      
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.networks = [
            {label: 'New York', value: 123},
            {label: 'Rome', value: 456},
            {label: 'London', value: 789},
            {label: 'Istanbul', value: 321},
            {label: 'Paris', value: 654}
        ];
        this.initForm();
    }
```